# almost everywhere convergence vs uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L},m)$

Can someone explain to me why $f_{n}(x)=\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ converges almost everywhere to $0$ but not uniformly...

also why does $f_{n}(x)=n^{-1}\chi_{(0,n)}$ converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sketch the graphs of the first few $f_n$. You should be able to see why they behave as they do.

Comment: but how to show the first sequence converges a.e?

Comment: Given any $x$, it is not in any $(0,1/n]$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @HeidiE Well it surely converges pointwise to zero on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ because for $x>0$ there is always a $n$ such that $x>\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Perhaps before measure theory you should make sure you understand the basics of continuity and convergence. For instance, do you understand why the function $1/x$ is continuous, but not uniformly continuous, on $(0,1]$? What about the sequence of *continuous* functions $x_n = x^n$ on $[0,1]$? Does that sequence converge uniformly? To what?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis,DavisMitra: thanks, I see it now

Comment: Funny that @snarski's suggestion, which might be by far the most useful piece of answer on the whole page, is not even *acknowledged* by the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) For any $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$, if $x_0\not\in (0,1]$ then $f_n(x_0)=0$ for all $n$; if $x_0\in (0,1]$ there exists $N$ such that when $n>N$ we have $x_0\not\in (0,\frac{1}{n}]$, and then $f_n(x_0)=0$. So $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
(2) For $\epsilon_0=\frac{1}{2}$, for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $\frac{1}{N+2}\in (0, \frac{1}{N+1}]$, hence $|\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{N+1}]}(\frac{1}{N+2})-0|=1\geq \epsilon_0$. This means that $\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ does not uniformly converge t0 $0$.
(3) Since $|n^{-1}\chi_{(0,n)}|\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\frac{1}{n}\chi_{(0,n)}$  uniformly converges to $0$.

Comment: thank you, nicely and clearly explained